# Data Studio - Google Marketing Platform Partial Connection

Tags: looker-studio

Google Data Studio is connected successfully to our Campaign Data - However, It doesn't seem to pull through certain metrics, such as `Interactive Impressions`.

I'm starting to wonder whether this could be to do with the fact that it isn't available in Instant reports, but was wondering if someone more familiar could explain why this is the case.

Have tried reconnecting to data via the integration service, but this has not resolved the issue.

N/A

The metrics should appear appear in the connection manager/Data source manager , but their simply not in the current selections I have.

I'd juts like to know why this is the case, and whether there are any workarounds known?. I cant seem to find a reasonable explanation online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full range of metrics is not available in the Data Studio connection
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7245540?hl=en

"The dimensions and metrics available through Data Studio represent a subset of the fields available through the Campaign Manager Report Builder tool or the Campaign Manager API".

The same is true for Search Console and Youtube connectors, as well as far most 3rd party tools connectors.